# Extract tags or relevant keywords from text

Tags: java, text-mining, gate

I need to extract relevant keywords or concepts similar to the [AlchemyAPI's concept tagging](http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/concept/) method.

I would like to know if there's any tool that can provide something similar to the "concept tagging" of text or classification, not just steeming words or regex only.

A stand alone solution is preferably in my case as I have a lot of data and it reaches the rate limit quickly for Yahoo Term Extraction and AlchemyAPI..

E.g. 
Input:

> With that said Its the democratic publics decision on whether they agree or disagree

Ouputs:

> Decision making

Answer (score 0):

This is called Text Classification

Here is a 5-part video series on doing what you need with a tool called RapidMiner

http://vancouverdata.blogspot.ca/2010/11/text-analytics-with-rapidminer-loading.html